# RegExp function not working with alternation

Tags: javascript, regex, alternate, alternating

```
string=string.replace(RegExp(filter[a]+" | "+filter[a],"g"),filter[a])
```

For some reason, this isn't affecting both the filter followed by the space and the filter with a space in front. Assuming the filter is ",", it would take the second side and only replace " ," rather than " ," and ", ". The filter is user-specified, so I can't use a normal regular expression (which DOES work) such as `string=string.replace(/, | ,/g,filter[a])`
Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work and how to make it work?

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete runnable example that we can use to reproduce the error you are getting? Please make sure that all variables you refer to are defined in your example code so that we can run it without requiring modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:

```
s = 'abc, def,ghi ,klm'
a = ','
s = s.replace(RegExp(a + " | " + a, "g"), a)
"abc,def,ghi,klm"
```

Remember that you regular expression won't replace `" ,  "` with `","`. You could try using this instead:

```
" ?" + filter[a] + " ?"
```